# Frobenius norm bound

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces

Is there any way to bound the Frobenius norm of a product of square matrices $A,B$ and a vector $x$ in the following way:

$$
\|ABx\|≤ \|Ax\|\text{ and }\|B\|.
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $A$ is invertible, then $$\|ABx\|=\|ABA^{-1}Ax\|\leq\|ABA^{-1}\|\|Ax\|=\kappa(A)\|B\|\|Ax\|,$$ 
where $\kappa(A)=\|A\|\|A^{-1}\|$ is the condition number of $A$. So yes, $\|ABx\|$ can be bounded by "something" involving $\|Ax\|$ and $\|B\|$ if $A^{-1}$ exists.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is no. Set 
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & c \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \quad 
B  = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
$$
where $c > 0$ and let $x = (1,0)^T$, then $Ax$ is the zero vector but $\|ABx\| = c$ can be arbitrarily large.